# Problems reading text from file

Tags: android, text, stream, inputstream

I'm trying to read some text from a .txt file, here's my code:

```
String filePath = bundle.getString("filepath");

        StringBuilder st = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File f = new File(sd, filePath);
            FileInputStream fileis = new FileInputStream(f);
            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    fileis));
            String line = new String();
            while ((line = buf.readLine()) != null) {
                st.append(line);
                st.append('\n');
            }
            Log.i("egor", "reading finished, line is " + line);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.i("egor", "file not found");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("egor", "io exception");
        }

        reader.setText(st.toString());
```

The text looks like this:

> This is a sample text to test

The .txt file is created in Windows notepad.

And here's what I'm getting:

[image]

What's wrong with my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks like encoding problem to me..add encoding to new InputStreamReader(fileis)

Comment: @evilone, thanks, how can I do that?

Comment: Try adding "UTF-8" for example or encoding what you are using for saving this text document in notepad, as second parameter of InputStreamReader constructor, documentation -  http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the file in utf-8 (unicode) format? For some reason, Notepad always adds a byte-order mark to unicode files, even when the byte-order is irrelevant. When interpreted as ASCII or ANSI, the BOM will be seen as several characters. It's possible this is what's causing your problem.

If so, the solution is to use a more competent text editor than Notepad, or write code that checks for a BOM first in all unicode files.

If none of this makes sense to you, try googling 'unicode' and 'byte-order mark'.

Comment: You're right, the problem was using Notepad. I've created another file using Notepad++ and now it's all right. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Wrap a FileReader object in the BufferedReader object instead. 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html

```
File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File file = new File(sd, filePath);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

String line = "";

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    st.append(line);
    st.append("\n");
}

br.close();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, have tried that, but it gives me the same result

Comment: @Egor: Strange, making a plain text file with that text in Eclipse and reading it that way gives me the correct result.

Comment: Seems like this is an encoding issue, something wrong with my notepad. I'll try to create the file in another editor. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, it surely is, I've done a file using Notepad++ and now it works fine.

Comment: Do not create with another editor. If you save your text file in notepad, you can select encoding from save dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the folowing code

```
File f = new File(str);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        byte[] mydata1 = new byte[(int) f.length()];
        fis.read(mydata1);
System.out.println("...data present in 11file..."+new String(mydata1));
```